# When will Django support Python 3.x?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I understand Django can only be run on Python 2.7 or below.  When will it run on Python 3.1 or above?  I see that Django 1.3 is coming out, does that support Python 3.x?

Comment: Did you ask the Django developers?  They might know more about the future of Django.

Comment: When WSGI gets standardized in Python 3.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler: What? Two weeks ago? :-) http://mail.python.org/pipermail/web-sig/2011-January/004979.html

Comment: @Lennart you know what I mean. When it's officially accepted/implemented...

Comment: well, it *is* accepted. That's my point. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might run on Python 3 by the end of summer. http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2130853 I don't know if that means "officially" or not, but it doesn't sounds like it, so official support is probably slightly later.

The question is why you want to know? You can't run it on Python 3 today. That's all that matters. The day you can run it on python 3, then it matters. Before that it doesn't. [Except to those doing the porting, of course ;-) ].

Predicting the future is easy. It's making the predictions come true that is the hard part. :-)

Comment: Wow.  Have you ever tried *planning* a project development roadmap beyond, say... lunchtime the same day?

Comment: @Steve: A relevant comment, if porting Django is doable before lunch. :-)

Answer (score 29):

Currently Django has passed py3k test.
The last port has been made available at [Vinay Sajip repository in BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/django/)
Check also news at [PortingDjangoTo3k](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PortingDjangoTo3k)

And, finally, news from PyCon 2012:

[Django 1.5 will bring experimental support for py3k](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2012/mar/13/py3k/).

Maybe targeting up to python 3.3 as both will be released in the same period (python 3.3 is scheduled for august 2012)

Comment: Couldn't Vinay use GitHub where there are 630 Django forks, rather than BitBucket where there are two?

Comment: @Tobu: You're missing the point. What exactly have those 630 forks on GitHub achieved? Why does it matter, since it's perfectly easy to pull a clone from BitBucket and work with it? I like GitHub, I've nothing against it. But I've nothing against BitBucket either, and collaborate on projects using both those services.

Comment: We plan to offer first-class, production-ready support for Python 3 in our next release, Django 1.6.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5-beta-1/#python-compatibility  we’re recommending that Django 1.5 not be used in production under Python 3. Instead, use this opportunity to begin porting applications to Python 3.

Comment: Django works fine in 3.x but one of the more critical packages it relies on, MySQL-python, doesn't.  May as well be a car without wheels.

Comment: @NickT You are right, although for new projects you still can use several different databases others than MySQL. Anyway, what about [MySQL connector](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-python.html) ? It doesnt a valid alternative for you?

Answer (score 4):

loewis has been working on a port of django to python 3 for a while.

https://bitbucket.org/loewis/django-3k

On Sept 9th, 2011 jacob (on of the core devs) started the py3k feature branch and pulled these changes in.

https://github.com/django/django/tree/features/py3k

AFAIK, no official release number or date has been set for when django will support python 3. More info on this thread:

http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/abede3685ad0302/573c1e0ff35e1ab7

Answer (score 3):

[Django 1.5 supports python 3k right now](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#python-3-support), but it is still experimental:

> [Django] plan[s] to offer first-class, production-ready support for
>   Python 3 in [the] next release, Django 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

The official FAQ mentions it might take [a year or two](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/install/#can-i-use-django-with-python-3), but I don't know when was that last revised.

I've been trying hard to find exactly where I've read their exact policies on Python support, but based on Django's [release process](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/internals/release-process/), you can understand that it will take some considerable time as it will likely happen through a major release only. Even if they'd decide to provide Py3k support *today*, it could take anything from 1 to 4 major releases to deprecate support from Python 2.4 up to Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/install/#can-i-use-django-with-python-3

Django 1.3 will not run on Python3k.

Comment: Any idea when Django will support python 3?

Comment: Not yet. As far as I saw, there are people trying to get it done, like: https://bitbucket.org/loewis/django-3k/ but it seems that it still has a looong way to go

Answer (score 0):

Alex Gaynor thinks about making the port a google summer of code project:

http://alexgaynor.net/2011/feb/17/django-and-python-3-take-2/

Answer (score 0):

New version has been come out with Python 3 support (but still experimental). Check it out: https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2013/feb/26/15/